# Helm: could not find tiller

Tags: openshift, kubernetes-helm

I'm getting this error message:

```
➜  ~ helm version
Error: could not find tiller
```

I've created `tiller` project:

```
➜  ~ oc new-project tiller
Now using project "tiller" on server "https://192.168.99.100:8443".
```

Then, I've created `tiller` into `tiller` namespace:

```
➜  ~ helm init --tiller-namespace tiller
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /home/jcabre/.helm.

Tiller (the Helm server-side component) has been installed into your Kubernetes Cluster.

Please note: by default, Tiller is deployed with an insecure 'allow unauthenticated users' policy.
To prevent this, run `helm init` with the --tiller-tls-verify flag.
For more information on securing your installation see: https://docs.helm.sh/using_helm/#securing-your-helm-installation
Happy Helming!
```

So, after that, I've been waiting for `tiller` pod is ready.

```
➜  ~ oc get pod -w
NAME                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
tiller-deploy-66cccbf9cd-84swm   0/1       Running   0          18s
NAME                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
tiller-deploy-66cccbf9cd-84swm   1/1       Running   0          24s
^C%
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 72):

Try deleting your cluster tiller

```
kubectl get all --all-namespaces | grep tiller
kubectl delete deployment tiller-deploy -n kube-system
kubectl delete service tiller-deploy -n kube-system
kubectl get all --all-namespaces | grep tiller
```

Initialise it again:

```
helm init
```

Now add the service account:

```
kubectl create serviceaccount --namespace kube-system tiller
kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller
kubectl patch deploy --namespace kube-system tiller-deploy -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"serviceAccount":"tiller"}}}}'
```

This solved my issue!

Comment: On the last `kubectl patch` command it gave me the error `Error from server (NotFound): deployments.apps "tiller-deploy" not found`

Comment: From version 3.0 helm init is no longer required and tiller is gone

Comment: @theduck
The first command kubectl get all --all-namespaces | grep tiller give the below output:
tiller        service/tiller-deploy   ClusterIP   10.104.79.35   <none>        44134/TCP                3h58m
tiller        deployment.apps/tiller-deploy   0/1     0            0           3h58m

However, when I try to delete the deployment/service it is not found.
kubectl delete deployment tiller-deploy -n kube-system
Error from server (NotFound): deployments.extensions "tiller-deploy" not found

Answer (score 25):

You don't have helm configured yet, use the following command:

```
helm init
```

This will create `.helm` with `repository`, `plugins`, etc, in your home directory.

Background:
`helm` comes with client and server, if you have a different deployment environment, it might be possible that your helm server (known as `tiller`) is different, in that case, there are two ways to point to `tiller`

- set environment variable `TILLER_NAMESPACE`
- `--tiller-namespace` string         namespace of Tiller (default "kube-system")

For more details check the `helm` [READ.md](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/helm/helm.md) file.

Comment: @Jordi if you think this answered your question then, please accept it. Else, please post your further queries.

Answer (score 13):

First of all you need to create service account for teller to use in helm:

```
kubectl -n kube-system create serviceaccount tiller
kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller --clusterrole cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller
helm init --service-account tiller
```

To verify that Tiller is running:

```
kubectl get pods --namespace kube-system
```

[DigitalOcean Reference](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-software-on-kubernetes-clusters-with-the-helm-package-manager)

Comment: `helm init --service-account tiller` returning
`Error: unknown flag: --service-account`

Comment: admin1@POC-k8s-master:~/poc-cog/metrics-server$ kubectl get pods --namespace kube-system
NAME                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
tiller-deploy-86f55698f8-xf5d5           1/1     Running   0          29s

Comment: admin1@POC-k8s-master:~/poc-cog/metrics-server$ helm ls
Error: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps?labelSelector=OWNER%3DTILLER: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
admin1@POC-k8s-master:~/poc-cog/metrics-server$ helm init
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /home/admin1/.helm.
Error: error installing: the server could not find the requested resource

Comment: This is because version of your helm tiller. Check this [Helm Github Ref](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7052)

Answer (score 12):

You installed tiller into a non-default namespace, so you have to tell helm where to look.

```
helm --tiller-namespace tiller  version
```

Comment: That worked. Since I've installed tiller via terraform, I automatically added a namespace. Beware!

Answer (score 10):

Now you can upgrade to the **latest version of Helm or any version > 3.0.0.**

**You don't need to do**

```
helm init
```

**anymore**.

The Tiller and client directories are initialised automatically when you start using helm. As mentioned [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/6996#issuecomment-555010868)

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue, try to re-install helm by using the commands below:

**For linux: (Via Snap)**

**`sudo snap install helm --classic`**

**For Linux (from Binary source):**

1. Download your desired version
2. Unpack it `(tar -zxvf helm-v2.0.0-linux-amd64.tgz)`
3. Find the helm binary in the unpacked directory, and move it to its desired destination 
   (`mv linux-amd64/helm /usr/local/bin/helm)`

**For MacOS (Via brew):**

**`brew install kubernetes-helm`**

**For windows (Via Chocolatey):**

**`choco install kubernetes-helm`**

And finaly, intialize the `helm`:

```
helm init
```

Answer (score 2):

With helm 3 releases, we do not need tiller anymore. Try to upgrade the helm version to 3. It provides more security to your cluster.Because  tiller runs in your Kubernetes cluster with full administrative rights, which is a risk if somebody gets unauthorized access to the cluster. 
If you migrate to helm3, you do not need to do helm init thereafter because helm version 3 is a tiller-less architecture.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
cp /usr/local/bin/tiller ~/.helm/
```

and check if the helm is deployed on server with

```
helm version
```